# how to upgrade next month last day of variable in mysql stored procedure?

Tags: mysql

```
In my while loop procedure (IN start_date date)
DECLARE data_date date;
set data_date=start_date;   

while data_date<end_date do
    insert into t1
    ……
    where date=data_date 

    set data_date=SELECT LAST_DAY(data_date + INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
```

It gets wrong because `set data_date=SELECT LAST_DAY(data_date + INTERVAL 1 MONTH);` but it works `SELECT LAST_DAY(data_date + INTERVAL 1 MONTH)`  out of the procedure. How can I upgrade my `data_date` variable based on `select last_day(……)` method.

Comment: Either remove SELECT keyword (`SET data_date=LAST_DAY(data_date + INTERVAL 1 MONTH);`, preferred) or wrap this SELECT query with parenthesis (or use SELECT INTO).

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT LAST_DAY(data_date + INTERVAL 1 MONTH) into data_date` works.